# A place to provide positive feedback about SE (like a comment board)

Tags: feature-request, information-display, feedback

I just wanted to post a note about how much I value / enjoy the Stack Overflow community.  Nothing that warrants a response, just a place that is like the index cards customers can draw / hang in [5 Guys Burgers and Fries](http://www.fiveguys.com/) joints. A place to show honest appreciation for this wonderful community.

I know there is the risk of "the 4chan effect", where it becomes overrun by spamming with a single purpose in mind. We need to be able to trust users enough that our fear of what evil the bad ones might do does not inhibit the creation of cool/useful things for the honest ones.

Comment: It seems like the only existing way to submit positive feedback about the site would be through this page [http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/other)

Comment: twitter works..when it's up...

Comment: Just positively and constructively participate within the Q&A's relevant to you. That should be thanks enough.

Comment: Go to a chatroom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your good stewardship of the site (asking thoughtful, well-researched answerable questions, providing helpful answers, voting and flagging when appropriate, providing well-placed, useful edits) is thanks enough, and we do appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @Robert's response, commending the site to your colleagues, friends and contacts is going to be valuable in the long run as it helps sustain growth.